# Is hadoop jar command class name case sensitive?

Tags: hadoop, command, case-insensitive, word-count

I just started learning hadoop 1.1.2 recently.

When I begin running the WordCount case, The two kind of codes are both fine.

**command A:**

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.1.2.jar WordCount input output
```

**command B:**

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.1.2.jar wordcount input output
```

The only difference is the main class name `wordcount`.

So my question is weather main class name `wordcount` case insensitive or not by default?

**Update**:

@Amar said `WordCount` won't work fine and I have checked that he is right. I was mislead by the document [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage). The official document need update.

But I still don't know why it must be `wordcount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running without `wordcount`, like:
`hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.1.2.jar input output`

You will receive something like follows:

```
Unknown program 'input' chosen.
Valid program names are:
  aggregatewordcount: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
  aggregatewordhist: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that computes the histogram of the words in the input files.
  dbcount: An example job that count the pageview counts from a database.
  grep: A map/reduce program that counts the matches of a regex in the input.
  join: A job that effects a join over sorted, equally partitioned datasets
  multifilewc: A job that counts words from several files.
  pentomino: A map/reduce tile laying program to find solutions to pentomino problems.
  pi: A map/reduce program that estimates Pi using monte-carlo method.
  randomtextwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random textual data per node.
  randomwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random data per node.
  secondarysort: An example defining a secondary sort to the reduce.
  sleep: A job that sleeps at each map and reduce task.
  sort: A map/reduce program that sorts the data written by the random writer.
  sudoku: A sudoku solver.
  teragen: Generate data for the terasort
  terasort: Run the terasort
  teravalidate: Checking results of terasort
  wordcount: A map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
```

So basically the first argument **is NOT the main-class name**, rather it is the example program's name which you want to run.

So, it shouldn't even accept `WordCount`, it isn't for me.
The following command has the same result as shown above:

`bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar WordCount LICENSE.txt output`

**For your information:** The main-class is already defined in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file contained in the jar :
`Main-Class: org/apache/hadoop/examples/ExampleDriver`

Comment: The document [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/commands_manual.html#jar) says the usage is `Usage: hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args...`, so `wordcount` should be the `mainClass`. I checked again, and found `WordCount` does not work fine. But the document [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage) mislead me.

Comment: What exactly in the above answer you did not understand?

Comment: You need to specify the mainclass only if you do not have it specified inside your jar's manifest. The square bracket in the document suggests that it is optional. And this is a different jar! In this case the first argument this jar expects is the example program's name (eg treasort, wordcount etc...). Simple.

Comment: I know now that `wordcount` is one of the MapReduce programs in `hadoop-examples-1.1.2.jar`. Thanks @Amar.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly case-sensitive, since it's trying to load the class `WordCount` or `wordcount` from the jar, depending on the casing. Since Java is case sensitive in this regard, so too is `hadoop jar`.

Comment: I unzip the hadoop-examples-1.1.2.jar file and don't find class `wordcount` with lower case.

Comment: And you probably shouldn't. It'll likely be a class named WordCount in a file named WordCount.java.

Comment: So the class name is `WordCount`, not `wordcount`. How does `command B` work fine?